# Advice for App communication between devices

Tags: android, ios

I would like to enable direct communication between devices...
To make things simple the App on one device will act as the master, and there can be from 0 to 2,3,4 slave devices.
The trick is : how can the slave devices be constantly listening to the master App signal without draining too much power, and with the bare minimum connection requirements?

I heard about Google's NearbyAPI, but it does not allow to listen from a Service (except with Bluetooth).

Has anyone been working for this kind of feature ? What was the best solution you found ? Thank you for reading!

Comment: There's a variety of things you can do, but its all limited.  The problem is that your phone doesn't have a constant IP address and is probably behind a NAT.  So normal internet sockets don't work well.  You can do bluetooth.  You can do it if you're all on the same wifi network.  You can do it via wifi direct or similar tech if you're within a hundred meters or so of each other.  But if you're talking about internet distances you need a server inbetween.

Comment: Thanx for this feedback. WE talk about à few meters distance (people in the same room or same car). This can also be about watermaking audio inaudible sounds... dunno if there are sdk that handle such things...

Comment: Then wifi direct may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Is there a way to use wifi direct with also iOS devices ? (it wasn't in the scope of my initial question, but that could help to figure things out)

Comment: I don't think so.  Unfortunately iOS is more locked down, so it can't really do custom bluetooth either.  If you're all on the same wifi network you can probably do direct internet connections, assuming your router doesn't NAT it out.

Answer (score 1):

For who might be interested, I found 2 promising libraries :

[AirTube](https://github.com/thinktube-kobe/airtube/wiki/Technical-Introduction) and [Underdark](https://github.com/udark)  - Although I did not try it, it looks nice.